# No main manifest attribute (Heroku deployment)

Tags: java, maven, heroku, web-deployment

I'm trying to follow [these](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java) instructions on how to deploy a java web app on Heroku, tried so many ways but I keep on getting different erros. Clearly I am missing something.

I have a dropwizard app and it runs fine locally without Heroku.

After following this tutorial my pom file looks as below:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.yammer</groupId>
<artifactId>dropwizard-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Profile looks like this:

```
  web: java -jar target/dropwizard-demo-1.0.jar server com.yammer.ApiService
```

So when I run **heroku local web** I get the error: **no main manifest attribute, in target/dropwizard-demo-1.0.jar**

What on earth has happend to this manifest? Is maven not creating it? How can I make this thing work please?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your `Procfile` should look like this:

```
web: java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.yammer.ApiService server
```

Also, you'll need to configure the `PORT` somewhere. Since I can't see your code, maybe you can try to emulate [this example app](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-kafka-demo-java).

There is also [Dropwizard support for Heroku's conventions](https://github.com/login-box/dropwizard-heroku).

Comment: nope. fixed it. but still not 100% sure it's right for you

Comment: Now I get this error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "server" (class com.yammer.ServiceConfiguration), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "http", "httpConfiguration", "logging", "loggingConfiguration"]).